setattr doesn't seem to have an effect when setting multi-level attributes
I'm writing a mod for a Ren'Py game that includes possibility to edit game's variables' values ("cheating"). Variables in the game include different ones from simple booleans to pretty complex ones (e.g simple_variable, obj.attr, obj.attr_a("some_id").attr_b). Here's a function I'm using to set new values to the variables/attributes (var_name is variable's name as a string and new_val is a value I'm trying to set):
def icmod_set_var_val(var_name, new_val): # e.g var_name is avatar.skills["combat"].level
    _list = var_name.split('.')
    o = globals()[_list[0]] # e.g <store.Avatar object at 0x0000000029388880>
    if len(_list) == 1:
        o = new_val
    elif len(_list) == 2:
        setattr(o, _list[1], new_val)
    elif len(_list) == 3:
        between_quotes = _list[1].split('"')[1::2][0] # e.g combat
        first_attr = _list[1].split('[')[0] # e.g skills
        _x = getattr(o, first_attr)[between_quotes] # e.g <store.Skill object at 0x00000000293883a0>
        setattr(_x, _list[2], new_val) # e.g _list[2] is level
    else:
        msgs.show('Something went wrong')

It doesn't work. When I'm using similar function to display modified values (using getattr) they're showing correctly. But when I use console or save a game and open it again I can see that the values are not actually changed. I even tried to use exec to change the values, but that doesn't seem to have a permanent effect either. So what am I doing wrong or missing here?
e: It seems to be a Ren'Py problem and the script itself works like intended (except the len(_list) == 1 part ofc). When I open a console without exiting the mod screen the values are changed. When I exit the mod screen changes are gone.

Do all uses of this code fail, or just some of the various reference formats you've implemented?  Some concrete examples of the problem would make this question much clearer.  The len==1 case is definitely broken, o = new_val is merely setting a local variable.  (The fact that o's value came from a global variable doesn't somehow give you the ability to change that variable, you'd have to change the value through globals()[...] just like you did when reading it.)

Seconding Jasonharper's comment, and adding that it might also be a good idea to read the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals.  Note this sentence: "For code within functions, this [the returned value from globals()] is set when the function is defined and remains the same regardless of where the function is called."

@jasonharper Yes, all uses fail (in the sense that they'll not "save"). I didn't even try len==1 case that'll definitely fail like you mentioned (let it be for a moment). I added an example to the code (exactly how it prints out in console). What bothers me is that everything seems to work like intended, but for some reason changes are not "permanent".
